# Highcharts series.data data type limitations?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Is there a limitation on the "array" method, specifically an amount of data points required to have it work?

I was using it to display large volumes of data just fine, but when I lowered the amount of points I was plotting, it seemed to break, and only plot one point, with an incorrect X value.

When I switched to use the object notation for data points (`{ x: new Date(), y: 100 }`) it worked just fine.

To clarify, the two notations seem to function differently with different amounts of data. The only thing different between the below example and my production code are the actual dates/values. Syntax is the same.

`[[Date.parse(i1), 100], [Date.parse(i2), 100]]`

`[{ x: Date.parse(i1), y: 100 }, { x: Date.parse(i2), y: 100 }]`

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series.data

Comment: The only difference between objects and arrays is with option `turboThreshold`, but this shouldn't affect you, I think. Create live demo (jsFiddle) with that issue so we can check this.

Answer (score 0):

The difference, as far as I can say, is that in the array notation, the `Date` object is not properly interpreted.

Using actual time stamps, both notations work the same.

Neither method should be affected by too few data points.

example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/yPLVP/148/

Comment: Sorry, I actually am using Date.parse() so it's rendering using the output of that. I'll update my example above to reflect that.

Comment: You'll need to provide an example of the problem in action then. As you can see in my fiddle above, they work the same when provided with the actual date stamp value instead of a function.

Comment: My assumption would be that it is a matter of how javascript parses arrays vs objects and has nothing to do with Highcharts specifically.